# How to toggle 2 divs on a click of a button?

Tags: jquery, html

Basically, i want to toggle an image with a flash file on click of a button. I want to show image in the beginning but want it to replaced by flash file. Also, i want the original image to show again on the click of the same button..

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work:

```
<div>
   <div id="image" style="display:block;">PLACE IMAGE HERE</div>
   <div id="flash" style="display:none;">PLACE FLASH HERE</div>
</div>

<div onclick="$('#image').toggle();$('#flash').toggle()">click me</div>
```

Comment: Unless I did something wrong, [it didn't work for me](http://jsfiddle.net/drFK5/).

Comment: One of the divs has to have `display:none;`

Comment: @JCOC611: I corrected it almost instantly and even with that two people noticed an error. You are of course right.

Comment: I'll give you a +1 for simplicity.

Comment: @apro: You have to include jQuery in head section: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: it did not work for me :(

check my code below

<html>
<head> <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" > </script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
   <div id="image" style="display:block;"><img src="image.jpg" /> </div>
   <div id="flash" style="display:none;">
   <embed src="flash_1.swf" width="750" height="450" name="flash file"  type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
</embed> </div>
</div>

<div onclick="$('#image').toggle();$('#flash').toggle()">click me</div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: what if I want to display 2 different types of images for "click here" button instead of single click here link. Something like: Click1.img with image1 and click2.img with Flash file?

Comment: @apro: `<div onclick="$('#image').show();$('#flash').hide()">Show image</div><div onclick="$('#image').hide();$('#flash').show()">Show flash</div>`

Comment: @lukled: Thanks for your help but instead of showing two different images, I just want to use 1 button image, but change the content of button as we click. I dont want to show 2 buttons at a time.

Comment: @apro: `$('#button_id').val('New text');` You should definitely find JavaScript/jQuery tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

```
var container = $('#container'),
    image = container.find('img'),
    flash = container.find('object'),
    button = $('#my-button');

image.hide();

put_flash_in();

button.click(function() {

   if (image.is(':visible')) {
       image.hide();
       flash.show();
   } else {
       image.show();
       flash.hide();
   }

});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HJTkv/).